# Segmentation Fault in Visual Studio Code while debug C Program

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, initialization, scanf, c-strings

I'm learning C. When I use this code on Linux I didn't get this kind of error. Can you show me how to fix it? I've tried many solutions but nothing worked T_T. Thanks in advance.

[image: segmentation error]

[image: code]

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3bD2.png)

Here's the code

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a;
    float x;
    char ch;
    char* str;

    printf("Enter integer number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nEnter real number : ");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("\nEnter a character: ");
    fflush(stdin); 
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    printf("\nEnter a string: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", str);

    printf("\nData:");
    printf("\n Integer: %d", a);
    printf("\n Real: %.2f", x);
    printf("\n Character: %c", ch);
    printf("\n String: %s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image.

Comment: no memory has been allocated for `str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this call

```
fflush(stdin);
```

has undefined behavior. Remove it.

Secondly in this call of scanf

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

you should prepend the conversion specifier with a space

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
      ^^^^^
```

Otherwise white space characters as the new line character '\n' will be read.

The pointer `str` is not initialized and has an indeterminate value

```
char* str;
```

So this call

```
scanf("%s", str);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You should declare a character array as for example

```
char str[100];
```

and call the function scanf like

```
scanf("%99s", str);
```

Comment: It solved the problem. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

A bare `char *str;` does not point to any valid memory, so you can't `scanf()` a string into it.

Either allocate some memory on the stack, e.g. `char str[512];`, or dynamically with `malloc()` and friends.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it because I'm new to it :(

Comment: I just did. The simplest is to change `char *str;` to `char str[512];` to allocate 512 bytes on the stack. But you should also understand exactly _what_ that does.

Comment: I still got that error :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure you didn't recompile the program or something if you still get that error after having made the change.

Comment: Now I got a warning but I don't know what this is about. I've just edited my post.